# After shift to another tab/category user logout

Tags: magento2

> Hello @all.
>
> Using Magento version 2.4.2 here getting the issue on the fronted user
> login successfully then the user moves to multiple tabs/category LIKE
> [ men, brands, etc.]. while moving he found he was logged out.
>
> **Note: Actually using multiple instances once heavy load on server1 shifts to server 2 that's the time the user logout.**
>
> Change the cookies/session time for 3 days. but still getting issues.
> Can anyone please guide me on this?
>
> Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Could you kindly verify that the settings are configured for the correct store view? Additionally, please review the logs for any errors related to cookies.

Comment: Are you using redis cache in your project?

Comment: No redis cache using the varnish

Comment: @arjun sorry not using any catche.

Comment: @GrazittiDev
Edit the Question please review then please

Comment: @Vivek It appears that you're not utilizing the global variable folders, which are responsible for managing cache and cookies. Instead, you can opt for database (DB) or Redis to store cache and cookies, regardless of using files.

Comment: @GrazittiDev I want to know muck about this. can you please brief me on this? how can we declare in DB or Redis to store cache and cookies,

Answer (score 0):

You can update the setting in **env.php** for Redis like given below

```
'session' => [
    'save' => 'redis',
    'redis' => [
        'host' => 'hostname',
        'port' => '6379',
        'password' => '',
        'timeout' => '2.5',
        'persistent_identifier' => '',
        'database' => '2',
        'compression_threshold' => '2048',
        'compression_library' => 'gzip',
        'log_level' => '1',
        'max_concurrency' => '20',
        'break_after_frontend' => '5',
        'break_after_adminhtml' => '30',
        'first_lifetime' => '600',
        'bot_first_lifetime' => '60',
        'bot_lifetime' => '7200',
        'disable_locking' => '1',
        'min_lifetime' => '60',
        'max_lifetime' => '2592000'
    ]
],
'cache' => [
    'frontend' => [
        'default' => [
            'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
            'backend_options' => [
                'server' => 'hostname',
                'database' => '0',
                'port' => '6379',
                'password' => ''
            ]
        ],
        'page_cache' => [
            'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
            'backend_options' => [
                'server' => 'hostname',
                'database' => '1',
                'port' => '6379',
                'compress_data' => '0',
                'password' => ''
            ]
        ]
    ]
], 
'cache_types' => [
    'config' => 1,
    'layout' => 1,
    'block_html' => 1,
    'collections' => 1,
    'reflection' => 1,
    'db_ddl' => 1,
    'compiled_config' => 1,
    'eav' => 1,
    'customer_notification' => 1,
    'config_integration' => 1,
    'config_integration_api' => 1,
    'full_page' => 1,
    'config_webservice' => 1,
    'translate' => 1,
    'vertex' => 1
],
```